# Implement function that returns 'Heads' or 'Tails' with equal probability

Tags: python

Implement function that returns 'Heads' or 'Tails' with equal probability.
I was thinking about just using a regular random.randrange module for this one, but I am not sure how that would work using actual words. Or if that would even be correct since the question specifies that they have equal probability.

Thank you, and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you take another look at the documentation before asking questions on SO (and in your case, especially random.choice). http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html.

Comment: `random.choice(['Heads', 'Tails'])`

Comment: @root: does random.choice use uniform distribution (discrete)?

Comment: @maverik - I think so, yes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `random.randrange` safely here. An if statement suffices to switch between the two cases.

```
import random

def coin_toss():
  if random.randrange(2):
    return 'Heads'
  else:
    return 'Tails'
```

Of course, it's easier to use `random.choice`:

```
def coin_toss():
  return random.choice(['Heads', 'Tails'])
```

Comment: What about ``random.choice(['Heads', 'Tails'])`` ?